# PHP - Parse Error: Unexpected EOF / Directories

Tags: php, mysql, eof, mkdir

I am getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Task2PHP\final\upload.php on line 205
```

I cannot find what's causing the problem, as all PHP blocks are opened and closes

```
    <?php
    include("login.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <title>FileStore - Upload Files</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./CSS/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <header id="header">


    <div id="header-content">
        <strong><h1>FileStore</h1></strong> Upload multiple files at once!
    </div>

    <div class="login-info" >

<?php



    if ($isLoggedin === false) {
        echo '  <form action="" method="POST">
                    Username: <input name="username" > 
                    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="8">
                              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
                </form>';
        echo "<p align='right'>You are not logged in.</p>";
        echo "<b><a href='registration.php'>Register</a></b>";


    }else{  
        echo $welcomeMsg;
    }   
?>

    </div>


    </header><!-- #header-->

    <section id="middle" align="center">

        <div id="container">

        <br><br>
            <div id="content">
                <strong><h1>Upload files</h1></strong><br><br>

                <div id="upload-file" >

<?php 


                    include("dbConfig.php");

                    $Username = $_SESSION["username"];

                    global $userid;

                    $Password = $_SESSION["password"];

                    $Password = md5($Password);

                    $sql = "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Username = '".$Username."'";

                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                            $userid = $row['UserID'];

                    }


                    echo $userid;

                    $dirname = (string)$userid;

                    $filename = ("/folder/" . "$dirname" . "/");

                    if (!file_exists($filename))

                    {

                                mkdir("files/$dirname", 0777);

                                if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                                echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";

                                $dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );

                                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";

                                }

                    } else {


                            if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                            echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";

                                $dest = ("files/" . $dirname . "{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                                foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $dest );

                                echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";


                        }
                        echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
                        }




                    // }




                        // if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

                        // echo "<div id='files_table'><table class='center'.><tr><td>";



                                // foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

                                // move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "files/'".$userid."'{$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]}");

                                // echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], " uploaded.", "<br>";


                        // }
                        // echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
                        // }

?>
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                            <h1> Select files to upload:</h1>
                            <br>
                            <p>
                                <input type="file" name ="files[]" multiple min="1" /> 
                                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
                            </p>
                            <br>
                            <h2> You can select multiple files for upload. </h2>

                    </form>

        </div>

            </div><!-- #content-->
        </div><!-- #container-->

        <aside id="sideLeft">

            <div id="menu-x" align="center"><br>
            <strong>Menu</strong><br><br>

                    <div class="menu">
                        <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="upload.php">Upload</a></li>
                        <li><a href="files.php">Files</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="help.php">Help</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <br style="clear:left"/>
                    </div>

            </div>


        </aside><!-- #sideLeft -->

    </section><!-- #middle-->

    <footer id="footer">
        <strong>FileStore:</strong> A CMT 3315 Project by Brian Livori
    </footer><!-- #footer -->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Also, I am trying to create a directory linked to the User's UserID (MySQL) with mkdir. The directory is created, however, files are not uploaded into the new directory.

Any help please?

Comment: Uncomment the `}` after `echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";`

Comment: Great Scott! Please format your code, just made me cry a little.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `mysql_query`? It's deprecated because it's extremely dangerous, as you've demonstrated here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an unclosed `{` which is causing this error. If you indented your code correctly this wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Your last `else` block is not closed (the closing brace is commented out):

```
else {
    if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {

        foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){


        }
        echo "</td></tr></table></div><br><br>";
    }
```

Format your code properly and you would see this issue.

Comment: ahh ok thanks! regarding the block where you create a directoy, my code is supposed to 'ignore' if a directory already exsists, however it displayes that it already exists on the page. any way on how to fix this?

Comment: @Brian - Possibly, however I don't understand how the accepted post answers your question?